# How can I use LitElement with Webpacker (rails Webpack) for custom Web Components?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, ecmascript-6, polymer, lit-element

For those who may not know Rails now uses Webpacker, an integration with Webpack. There is a `/packs` dir that will get transpiled for use on a html page:

```
<script src="/packs/bundle-06cd8a4ad388853ace59.js"></script>
```

I have written a test web component.

```
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element';


class TestComponent extends LitElement {

  render(){
    return html`
      <!-- template content -->
      <p>ZZZZZZZZZZ</p>
    `;
  }
}
customElements.define('test-component', TestComponent);
```

I'm importing this into my `packs/bundle.js` as:

```
import '../web_components/test-component'
```

In the browser I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor LitElement cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

Webpack is turning this into:

```
var TestComponent = function (_LitElement) {
  _inherits(TestComponent, _LitElement);

  function TestComponent() {
    _classCallCheck(this, TestComponent);

    return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (TestComponent.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(TestComponent)).apply(this, arguments));
  }

  _createClass(TestComponent, [{
    key: 'render',
    value: function render() {
      return Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_lit_element__["b" /* html */])(_templateObject);
    }
  }]);

  return TestComponent;
}(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_lit_element__["a" /* LitElement */]);

customElements.define('test-component', TestComponent);
```

I'm not really sure of how to make this work, but I would really love to get started using web components.

Please help!!

Comment: same problem here

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a common [issue](https://github.com/Polymer/lit-element/issues/54).

Found a solution that works for me, hopefully thats helpfull to you too. Just add the following script tag inside `application.html.erb`. It's a polyfill, you can read more about it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs#using-webcomponents-bundlejs)

```html
<!-- ADD POLYFILL  -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs@2.4.3/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js"></script>

<!-- be sure that the webpack tags are AFTER the polyfill -->
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
<%= yield %>
```

the polyfill can also be added through [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs), but I prefere to just use the [CDN](https://unpkg.com/browse/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs@2.4.3/)